# Terraform interpolated values in tag keys

Tags: terraform

I use Terraform to create VMs with names based on `count.index`. I would like to create tags where the keys are dynamically based on `count.index`. I just couldn't get it working.

For VM01, tag should be "PatchCycle01 = centos" & for VM02, it should be "PatchCycle02 = centos".

```
  tags = {
    PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)} = "CentOS"
  }
```

I tried the above code but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key needs to be built with a [string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates) like this:

```
tags = {
  "PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}" = "CentOS"
}
```

If you are using something earier than Terraform 0.12, you will have to use the [map function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/map.html) which is deprecated now:

```
tags = "${map(
  "PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}", "CentOS"}"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @alian, I tried this, and it is not interpolating "${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}" .. and creating tag as-it is. So the tag created is 'tags.PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}:                              "" => <computed>'

Comment: @user3362908 odd. The documentation suggests that the map function is deprecated and the `{` `}` syntax replaces it. For now I'll suggest using map despite that it is deprecated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the map function which definitely supports computed keys, but which is deprecated.

Comment: I couldn't get map working as well, I am on Terraform v0.11.14, provider.azurerm v1.33.1.

Comment: Also, I tried to have two local map variables and conditional assign it to tag, it didn't work either.

Comment: The `map` function is entirely unnecessary here. You can just quote the left hand side like you had to do even when using the `map` function.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you are correct. I've rolled back my answer.

Comment: @user3362908 why did you claim that this didn't work?

Comment: Terraform 0.11 doesn't support expressions in map keys; the `map` function is required for 0.11. It's deprecated for 0.12 onwards because the `{` ... `}` syntax now supports arbitrary expressions for keys.

Comment: @MartinAtkins you are correct. I've consolidated my revisions of this answer into one that addresses newer Terraform and pre-0.12 Terraform.

Comment: Note also that Terraform 0.12 requires expressions to be given via interpolation into a string!  `tags = "${map("PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}", "CentOS)}"`

Comment: Right! Damn. See my revision comment on my latest fix. Nobody should use Terraform 0.11, it's like self-flaggelation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to properly quote the left hand side (the key of the map) for this to work:

```
locals {
  foo = "foo"

  map_test = {
    "PatchCycle${local.foo}" = "foo"
  }
}

output "foo" {
  value = local.map_test
}
```

Applying the above outputs the following:

```
foo = {
  "PatchCyclefoo" = "foo"
}
```

So for your example you would do something like this:

```
  tags = {
    "PatchCycle${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}" = "CentOS"
  }
```